# How I fix my pc?

Tags: system-installation, usb-installation

I'm having some trouble about Windows. I'm tired and didn't found a distribuition whom works on Intel chips. Anyone can help? I'm doing this because I've ramsonwared!

Comment: What are your system specifications? The latest Ubuntu LTS should work out-of-the-box on most Intel chips.

Comment: What is your *intel* chips?   Intel's IA64 was abandoned long ago now, by both Intel and even by GNU/Linux, so you'll need to be specific. Most intel manufactured chips today are *amd64* (also called x86_64) as the AMD 64-bit system won in the marketplace.   (*Your system likely wasn't intel's IA64 as it mostly sold for server use, though desktops were told briefly - but you've provided no actual specifics.. My current 2008 dell using intel chips runs all releases of Ubuntu fine by the way*)

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu.  You might receive better quality responses if your question better aligns with the title. For suggestions, see [ask]. Some specific recommendations for you to improve your question: are you looking to fix a Windows PC and remove malware (more appropriate in another forum).  If your question is instead about whether a fresh OS installation is an appropriate malware response, you could also check [does-switching-to-linux-remove-existing-computer-virus](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/37175/does-switching-to-linux-remove-existing-computer-virus)

Answer (score -1):

All linux distros work on Intel chips.

This forum prefers and understands Ubuntu.

Download the [Iso](https://releases.ubuntu.com/22.04/ubuntu-22.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso), copy it unto a stick (for that you'll need a working computer).

Else [buy](https://www.softwarebilliger.de/betriebssysteme/usb-live-stick/5685/usb-live-stick-linux-ubuntu-mit-64-bit-32-gb-usb-3.0) a stick.

When installing disable secureboot in you UEFI and make sure that the usb drive is in the boot order.